# How to add a tooltip to area chart after zoom interaction

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating an area chart in D3 that includes two main features:

1) a time slider to change the date range on the x axis and update the chart (similar to a brush-to-zoom)

2) a tooltip that appears on hover to show the exact value at a given date

These two features are working when the chart loads, but when I change the x axis range by dragging the slide I encounter a problem: the area chart transitions as it should by zooming in with a new axis and area, but when I hover to reveal the tooltip, the tooltip location and values do not match the new path of the line/area.

I have tried wrapping all the code that creates the tooltip objects (appended to `focus` var) in a function, and then recalling that function when the slider is moved. I have also tried storing the x scale in a variable that is updated when the time slider is moved, and passing that to the `drawFocus()` function. The tooltip still appears in the original location.

[Screenshot of where tooltip appears after zooming using time slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZVrM.png)

Pasting link to bl.ock for full code below, but I think the problem is coming from something in the `tipMove()` function which is called whenever the user hovers over the chart. (current_x is storing the x scale defined by the time slider):

```
// function that adds tooltip on hover
                function tipMove() {

                    // below code finds the date by bisecting and
                    // stores the x and y coordinate as variables
                    let x0 = current_x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
                    let i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);
                    let d0 = data[i - 1];
                    let d1 = data[i];
                    let d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

                    // place the focus objects on the same path as the line
                    focus.attr('transform', `translate(${current_x(d.date)}, ${y(d.value)})`);

                    // position the x line
                    focus.select('line.x')
                        .attr('x1', 0)
                        .attr('x2', x(d.date))
                        .attr('y1', 0)
                        .attr('y2', 0);

                    // console.log(x0)

                    // position the y line
                    focus.select('line.y')
                        .attr('x1', 0)
                        .attr('x2', 0)
                        .attr('y1', 0)
                        .attr('y2', height - y(d.value));

                    // position the text
                    focus.select('text').text(d.value).transition() // slowly fade in the tooltip
                        .duration(100)
                        .style("opacity", 1);

                    // show the circle on the path
                    focus.selectAll('.focus circle')
                        .style("opacity", 1)

};
```

Full code here: https://blockbuilder.org/bendoesdata/99c2ca152f760b6d93c923ee9462f4fa

I expect the tooltip to follow the line after the chart is zoomed on, but instead the tooltip follows the original path of the line (which isn't visible within the clip path anymore).